# How to send file/folder from desktop using ADB to multiple android devices connected to Windows 7 computer

Tags: android, batch-file, sdk, adb

Currently have a Windows computer with multiple Android devices connected via USB with debugging enabled.  Am trying to use 'adb' to transfer files simultaneously to all devices at the same time.  Researched and found the ADB+ batch file, but am not having any luck.  very new to adb and batch files, please help!!

Have used 'adb devices' command to ensure devices are listed.  Can utilize the 'adb push' command to send file to 1 device at a time, however very time consuming. Is there a way to use the 'adb push' command in some way to communicate with all attached devices at the same time?

Not sure how to execute 'adb+' command or if something needs to be changed within to make this work.  Using Windows 7 with the downloaded SDK platform-tools adb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code :

```
for /f %i in ('adb devices') do adb -s  %i push /path/to/local/file /mnt/sdcard/path/to/file
```

found sdcard path

```
adb shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!  Had to remove one '%' before each I variable to make it work.  

for /f %i in ('adb devices') do adb -s %I push /path/to/local/file /mnt/sdcard/path/to/file

Comment: having another issue with pushing file to the SD CARD.  using the above command, it keeps sending the file to the "Device Storage" instead of the mounted SD Card.  Any ideas??